# How to fix WatiN OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, memory, watin, out-of-memory

I'm iterating over a very large list of divs with WatiN (about 3000) and I'm getting the error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in WatiN.Core.dll
System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
   at WatiN.Core.UtilityClasses.UtilityClass.TryFuncFailOver[T](DoFunc`1 func, Int32 numberOfRetries, Int32 sleepTime)
   at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEElement.GetWithFailOver[T](DoFunc`1 func)
   at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEElement.GetAttributeValue(String attributeName)
   at WatiN.Core.Element.GetAttributeValueImpl(String attributeName)
   at WatiN.Core.Component.GetAttributeValue(String attributeName)
   at WatiN.Core.Element.get_OuterHtml()
   at WatiN.Core.Document.get_Html()
```

When clicking a div then getting the html of the browser.

Does anyone know of how to fix the memory issue? I am hoping I can use a different function or split the page somehow. Perhaps I will need to use something other than WatiN

The code is:

```
 foreach (Div d in browser.Divs)
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            d.Click(); // click div

                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250); //wait for new data to load

                            string url = "";
                            if (browser.Html.Contains("http://www.google.com/url?")) // check if an external link exists on the page - this causes the memory exception
                            {
```

Thanks for any help

Chris

Comment: please past the full method which contains this code.. so one can understand what heck it is you are even trying to do.. for example d.Click() what code behind happens there.. this looks rather messy in terms of code logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it was a problem with Internet Explorer as the amount of memory it used went beyond 1GB and presumably hitting the 32-bit .net object limit somewhere.

In my case running on a 64-bit system "fixed" (or rather, delayed) the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First do not user thread sleep when you wait for the page, you have browser.WaitForComplete()

if you are looking checking that the link take you to specific page you can check directly the browser url like this: browser.Url.Contains("address") ...

Comment: Note that Chris could be waiting on AJax or similar async calls to finish with the Thread.Sleep().  Not the best way, but WaitForComplete doesn't work for AJax-y loading.

Comment: Hi as it happens I was waiting for ajax that requires the thread.sleep - I should have posted enough code to make this clear